# Avoid synching collisions based on timestamp in Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to perform some kind of calculations from the large list of objects. When a new user adds/delete/updates an item to the list, I need to perform the calculations. I check the last modified timestamp from the list and perform he calculations only if needed. So for example, I generate calculations based on timestamp 1000. If someone modifies the list item, its timestamp will change and If it is > 1000, then I will perform calculations.

However for adding and removing, it works fine. But, I came across a weird situation while this failed while working offline.

So, say this is the list of items with the initial values which both the users(user A and user B) are having. And the total of value is: **600** based on the greatest last_modified:**3000**

[image]

Now both the users are offline and editing offline:

1. **User A** edited **item1** with value **400** at timestamp **4000**. So total of value becomes **900** based on the largest last_modified **4000**
2. **User B** edited **item3** with value **500** at timestamp **5000**. So total of value becomes **800** based on the largest last_modified **5000**

Currently both users are offline so server does not have any update. It looks like this on both the user's local database:

[image]

Now first **User B** goes online. And its data is synced to the firebase database. So on server we have total value: **800**.

This will happen when **User A** goes online:

- It updates the **item1** on server.
- Fetches total and **item3** from the server.
- Checks it total needs to be updated. Total generated timestamp says total generated at **5000**. So it is latest. No need to update.
- As **item1** is updated at the server, User B fetches the changes and checks if it needs to update the total. But seems good as timestamp of total generated is **5000**, and current total also says it was generated on **5000**.

So, both users contains something like this:

[image]

However, the actual total should be: **1100**. But, it will be **800**. The re-calculation will not happen as timestamp for total generated says it was generated at **5000** timestamp, and current also greatest is **5000**. So it assumes that the the total is generated from **5000** and it correct.

The reason calculation happens only when data modified is the performance. It takes almost *3 seconds* to perform calculations on *1000* records. It will grow larger over time. And it should not be the bottleneck because of this.

How can I solve this conflict?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you could add a *last_sync* property and update it when a user sync the data with the server (goes online). Then you would check for *last_modified* or *last_sync* in the future (compared to *timestamp*)

Comment: In firebase, it happenes automatically. We don't even know if the update is pending or not.

Comment: How are you setting the timestamps?

Comment: Through System.currenttimemillis()..

Comment: @kirtan403 Why don't you use the server value of firebase? I think that way the last one actually added in firebase will have the latest timestamp. Also it removes any possible inconsistancy between users local time settings.

Comment: Can you give an example of it? How will it resolves the values and when?

Comment: @AndréKool - It will have the save issue. The one syncs last will have the latest sync timestamp but had not added up modified data from the other user.

Comment: I guess you must first clarify the use case of your app. You might want to have a variable 'total' that will be updated. So you do not need to recalculate over and over. And this total variable won't affect the timestamp, in your scenario. Say for exam the last total is 800, then user A adds 200, and user B adds 100, you'll just be adding it to that variable, no need to recompute over the nodes one by one. It WILL consume much bandwidth if that's the case

Comment: Yes that might be an option, but there will be modifications, additions and deletions as well. And this is critical information for my app. I am doing it on small chunk of data and then aggregating it to get the final total. So getting this data currepted at some point where concurrent modifications can happen while offline, can lead to an undesirable state. And the small aggregations i am storing are also required to be shown in the app. So it will be beneficial by aggregating and storing it and it will also be useful while scaling.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried adding operator variable then get that value to calculate? Say you'll have a operator, value, and timestamp, then compute it on your code? Have you tried using Firebase's server timestamp? It should have no problem on the timestamp if you're using those numbers in comparing which is greater. Also, can you share your code so we can have check it better?