# Accessing Firebase Database from AsyncTask's Transaction

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I have reached a need where I need to access the Firebase Database from the asynctask where the transaction is going on.

So my setup is, I have an AsyncTask. In its `doInBackground` method, I call another method which contains the logic where I run the transaction. In the transaction's `doTransaction` method, I need to access the data from the different path and generate the new data (like some stats).

It looks something like this:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String para1 = params[0];
        String para2 = params[1];

        performCalculations(para1,para2);

        return null;
    }

    public void performCalculation(String para1, String para2) {
        DatbaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(para1);

        // Run the transaction here
        ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

                 TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();

                 DatabaseReference ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(param2);

                 ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new MyValueEventListener(taskCompletionSource));

                 try {
                    dataSnapshot = Tasks.await(taskCompletionSource.getTask());

                    // DOING SOME AWESOME THINGS HERE 
                    // And updating the mutable Data


                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Exception Catched");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                mutableData.setValue(stats);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Transaction was successful");

                }
            }

        }
    }

    private class MyValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {

        private final TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskSource;

        public MyValueEventListener(TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskSource) {
            this.taskSource = taskSource;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Looks like MyValueEventListener received the data");
            taskSource.setResult(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Looks like MyValueEventListener thrown an error");
            taskSource.setException(databaseError.toException());
        }

    }

}
```

Putting the logs all over the place, I encountered that It reaches to the `Tasks.await` statement.  But then `onDataChanged` callback is never called.

It is stuck at that point. No errors. No exceptions.

And the biggest issue is, from then, it stops all the callbacks for the whole application. All my activities are blocked because it never calls `onDataChanged`. Looks like it crashes inside or blocked by thread.

What's going on? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So, to get the latest data from ref inside a transaction, I have made the variable part of the class. And attached the value event listener to it. So it will keep it updated all the time. But, what if offline queued transaction will start running before triggering value event listener? Is there any priority what will execute first after going online after being offline for a while?

Here is my updated code:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot;

    ValueEventListener mListener;

    DatabaseReference ref2;

   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String para1 = params[0];
        String para2 = params[1];

        performCalculations(para1,para2);

        return null;
    }

    public void performCalculation(String para1, String para2) {

            TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();

            ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(param2);

            ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new MyValueEventListener(taskCompletionSource));

            try {
                    // Get the data first time before you proceed
                    dataSnapshot = Tasks.await(taskCompletionSource.getTask());

             } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Exception Catched");
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }

             // Register the value event listener to keep the data updated
             mListener = new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mDataSnapshot = dataSnapshot
                Log.v(TAG, "Data updated");
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         };

        ref2.addValueEventListener(mListener);


        DatbaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(para1);

        // Run the transaction here
        ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

                 // Perform some stuff based on mDataSanpshot



                mutableData.setValue(stats);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Transaction was successful");
                    ref2.removeEventListener(mListener);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // My value event listener here ... 

}
```

Comment: It's like you are using transaction process (background thread) inside background task. Why you want MyAsync task? performCalculation method is already doing task in background thread

Comment: So can I block transaction thread until it receives the data from the TaskCompletionSource? It won't affect my UI thread?

Comment: I don't think so! Try it once!

Comment: OMG! My Previous structure was only performCalculation, But because of blocking I converted it to the AsyncTask! I'm trying..

Comment: I checked this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data It's callback method so it won't affect on UI thread

Comment: Yes, As all the db operations are done on separate thread, this must be on a separate thread. I think, I should try blocking it once.

Comment: A transaction can only ensure consistent data within the ref where you started it.  You can't Assume that refs outside that location will be consistent with the one of the transaction.  You can't stop the transaction to listen to other refs.  You can't block the transaction without inviting major problems.  These are limitations of the system.  You can expand the scope of your transaction to a path that's above both refs to ensure all data below them are consistent, but your app may have scalability problems under heavy write concurrency.

Comment: The problem is both of them are in a full separate path, Even if I try to get the most high level, there can be too much data inside that node. So, it looks like I am again stuck at the problem. :/

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get a more informed answer from a Firebaser, such as FvP.  Until then, I'll offer that I'm pretty sure your task wait in `runTransaction()` is creating a deadlock.  You can see the thread the callbacks run on with a `Log` statement similar to this:

```
Log.i(TAG, "doTransaction: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

`doTransaction()` runs on the `FirebaseDatabaseWorker` thread.  Listener callbacks run on the main (UI) thread and are (I would guess) driven by events dispatched from the DB worker thread.

Blocking the DB worker thread will cause the listener callbacks to never fire.  The task never completes, so the `Task.await()` is never released.

Comment: Okay. So the running in the AsyncTask is causing me the deadlock, right? Can i block runTransaction thread with Tasks.await?

Comment: @kirtan403: You have no control over the thread `runTransaction()` runs on.  It is always the `FirebaseDatabaseWorker` thread.  Using `AsyncTask` doesn't help.  And you should never block `FirebaseDatabaseWorker` thread.

Comment: I have checked the thread, Its FirebaseDatabaseWorker, and before the transaction (after removing AsyncTask) its main thread. I'm locked now!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done anything with TaskCompletionSource's yet, so don't immediately see what going on there. But in general I try to steer away from such constructs as they complicate the code without significant benefit.

The Firebase Database client performs all network and disk I/O on a separate thread and then surfaces the calls to your methods on the main thread. By using this and reordering some of the calls, I think you can do away with a lot of the code:

```
public void performCalculation(String para1, String para2) {
    DatbaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(para1);
    DatabaseReference ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(para2);

    ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { }
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                    // DOING SOME AWESOME THINGS HERE 
                    // And updating the mutable Data
                }
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Transaction was successful");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    );
```

Comment: I tried that also. At first, I implemented in this way only. But transaction doesn't seem to update data when re-run. Because when accessing data from the ref2 value, it needs to be final, so even if the transaction is re-run, it uses the old data to calculate another data on which I would like to write.

Comment: That's the reason, I moved the database callback inside runTransaction

Comment: I am using TaskCompletionSource, so that I can simply wait for the data to be returned and then continue execution. From Doug Stevenson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJqakuas_6g

Comment: @kirtan403 I don't think you want to register a listener inside a transaction or block the thread the transaction is on.  Frank's strategy looks much more reliable to me.  I'm still unclear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish - I see your code, but I don't know what your intent is.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for looking into it. :) .. So, my data which is going to be written on `ref` depends on the data coming from `ref2`. That's why I am running a transaction on `ref` because if 2 users updates the data offline, `ref`'s data should include both's updates which is on `ref2`. So, whenever the transaction is re-run it needs to have the latest data from `ref2`, else it will generate the same data without getting the updates. So, if I do what Frank has suggested, it will hold the final reference of the dataSnapshot and will always run the transaction on the old data.

Comment: That is what was happening to me. So, I converted that helper class to `AsyncTask` and created `TaskCompletionSource` so that it can grab the data when `doTransaction` runs and wait till it receives with `Tasks.await` and then execute the transaction.. So that the generated data is generated from the all updated/latest data.

Comment: You can't get all the prior changes to a ref by using a listener.  A listener will only initially see the latest value at the location.  If a location gets overwritten multiple times, and your listener wasn't registered the entire time, you won't see all those individual snapshots.  If you need to record a history of things that happened, you should instead use push() to put a value in a queue, then delete children out of that location when you're done with the data in that location.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know that problem. I also contacted Firebase support team regarding the issue. I have been contacted by Gio from the support team, and this is what we have came around a solution. This the problem I wanted to solve (http://stackoverflow.com/q/38723823/1820644) . The only solution is a transaction. And for that transaction, I need the latest data, whenever the transaction runs.

Comment: That is why I am registering single value event listener inside the transaction. And that path is  under `keepSynced(true)` so that I can get the latest value. I've also tried a new thing which can have the latest value inside a transaction(see the updated question) , but I'm afraid of only one thing. What if offline queued transaction will start running before triggering value event listener? Is there any priority what will execute first after going online after being offline for a while?

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm updating the question, give me a minute